# The source of Muay Thai techniques terminology

Tags: technique, muay-thai, terminology

I guess, a lot of people here are familiar with "Muay Thai - The Art of Fighting" book, or at least with its list of Muay Thai techniques copypasted all over the Muay Thai related web.

The list where all techniques are divided into Cherng Muay, Kon Muay, Mae Mai and Look Mai with further fist/elbow/knee/foot division.

All of the techniques have fancy names often referring to Ramakien epic as  opposed to simple modern technique lists (like one on the Wiki).

Where does this list come from? I believe there must be a certain major Thai source.

Comment: **Welcome to the site!** This is a really nice question.

Comment: This might be a good place to start, http://tagmuaythai.com/muay-thai-words-phrases/  but I don't know enough to answer the question better.  Maybe someone who speaks Thai can give a literal translation.  Sometimes that is enough to see where the terms come from.

Answer (score 4):

Muay Thai is definitely well related to The Epic of Ramakein. Also the names of techniques do resemble certain events or names in it.

However, the point to note is that, The Ramakein is Thai interpretation of Hindu  **Ramayana** from India. [Here is a reference link for more info](https://kickboxing2008.com/muay-thai-ramayan-connection/)

The characters and events in both these mythological stories are more or less identical.

Since a major chunk of martial arts is believed to have improvised or originated from Gautama Buddha (Indian/Chinese origin) with his **18 Hands** physical training ([source](http://flowingzen.com/4862/18-luohan-hands-qigong/), considered to be a huge influence in Martial arts world), the source of these names may have some sort of mysterious relation to the this south east country.

Comment: Luckily I found some :) See if it helps!